# Flask @route parameter correct syntax

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to parse a REST-like URL that looks something like:

```
/user/bob/admin/
/user/sam/admin/
/user/bob/help/
```

Where the text after the '/user/' is the variable in question.  I tried creating a function like:

```
@app.route('/user/<username>/admin/')
def user():
  #etc...
```

This didn't work though... is this possible?

THANKS!!

EDIT

this is all I could get... is there something better?

```
@app.route('/user/<name>/<panel>')
def act(name=None, panel=None):
```

Comment: Is it not working? First one doesn't work, second example should work.

Comment: Your first example needs to actually accept a `username` argument, otherwise you'll get a `TypeError`.

Comment: Please put that as an answer.